# Where is the best place to level up in kingdom hearts 2.5 remix

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

I am currently level 54 and I am struggling to level up at a quick pace.

What is the quickest method to level up to the point where I can beat the game?

Comment: Which game are you talking about? Your question is very vague and there are two playable games on the 2.5 remix.

Answer (score 1):

The best and quickest way to level up in 2.5 is to equip gull wing keyblade and equip the ability experience boost.

After doing that go to the world that never was and go to the first checkpoint. Run into the first 3 enemies and let them get your hp to below half, this will allow you to get 3 times as much exp. After that kill all the enemies while maintaining below half hp by making your way to the top of the world, rinse and repeat till level 99.

A note to add is there was a faster way in 2 but that spot no longer works. It was in pride lands on pride rock but the enemies drop hp orbs now so you do not get 3 times as much exp.